# Getting a 403 when calling Azure Resource Rate API using certificate auth

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure

I am trying to create a console app that can call the [Azure Resource Rate API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004) using certificate authentication. For this, I used the following branch [GitHub link](https://github.com/HarvestingClouds/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api).

I am getting a 403 error. I've added an Web App to my Azure AD. In the manifest, I've copied the key credentials from the certificate I've signed using the following PowerShell commands;

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=RateCardCert"
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature  
$bin = $cert.RawData $base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)
$bin = $cert.GetCertHash() 
$base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin) 
$keyid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() 
$jsonObj = @ customKeyIdentifier=$base64Thumbprint;keyId=$keyid;type="AsymmetricX509Cert";usage="Verify";value=$base64Value} 
$keyCredentials=ConvertTo-Json @($jsonObj) | Out-File "keyCredentials.txt"
```

In de console app, I use the following function to get the token;

```
public static string GetOAuthTokenFromAAD_ByCertificate(string TenanatID, string ClientID, string CertificateName)
    {
        //Creating the Authentication Context
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", TenanatID));
        //Console.WriteLine("new authContext made");
        //Creating the certificate object. This will be used to authenticate
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        //Console.WriteLine("empty 'cert' made, null");
        //The Certificate should be already installed in personal store of the current user under 
        //the context of which the application is running.
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);


        try
        {
            //Trying to open and fetch the certificate
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var certs = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, CertificateName, false);
            //Checking if certificate found
            if (certs == null || certs.Count <= 0)
            {
                //Throwing error if certificate not found
                throw new Exception("Certificate " + CertificateName + " not found.");
            }
            cert = certs[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the certificate store
            store.Close();
        }

        //Creating Client Assertion Certificate object
        var certCred = new ClientAssertionCertificate(ClientID, cert);

        //Fetching the actual token for authentication of every request from Azure using the certificate
        var token = authContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", certCred);

        //Optional steps if you need more than just a token from Azure AD
        //var creds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token.AccessToken);
        //var client = new ResourceManagementClient(creds); 

        //Returning the token
        return token.AccessToken;
    }
```

This is the part of the code that makes the URL and puts in the request (the xxxx part is replaced by the ClientID of the webapp that I've registered in Azure AD);

```
//Get the AAD User token to get authorized to make the call to the Usage API
        string token = GetOAuthTokenFromAAD_ByCertificate("<MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "RateCardCert");


            // Build up the HttpWebRequest
        string requestURL = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}",
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ARMBillingServiceURL"],
                   "subscriptions",
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionID"],
                   "providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0044P' and Currency eq 'EUR' and Locale eq 'nl-NL' and RegionInfo eq 'NL'");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURL);

        // Add the OAuth Authorization header, and Content Type header
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        // Call the RateCard API, dump the output to the console window
        try
        {
            // Call the REST endpoint
            Console.WriteLine("Calling RateCard service...");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RateCard service response status: {0}", response.StatusDescription));
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var rateCardResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("RateCard stream received.  Press ENTER to continue with raw output.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(rateCardResponse);
            Console.WriteLine("Raw output complete.  Press ENTER to continue with JSON output.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Convert the Stream to a strongly typed RateCardPayload object.  
            // You can also walk through this object to manipulate the individuals member objects. 
            RateCardPayload payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RateCardPayload>(rateCardResponse);

            Console.WriteLine(rateCardResponse.ToString());
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("JSON output complete.  Press ENTER to close.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \n\n{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : ""));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I just don't know what I have to do anymore, what am I missing here??

Full return of the console is:

> Calling RateCard Service...
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: Have you given the app permissions in Azure AD? 403 indicates authorization failure, not authentication, so the certificate is probably working fine.

Comment: I've added permissions to the app by going to AAD-> App Registrations --> appname--> Required Permissions. I've added 'Windows Azure Service Management API' and 'Windows Azure Active Directory'. For the latter, I've added all the permissions (to be sure) but still the 403 persists..

Comment: Did you press the Grant Permissions button? Adding the permissions only tells that it requires those, but granting them is a separate action.

Comment: I have done that, to no avail unfortunately. Still the same console output, I am getting lost :P

Comment: Ahh, you are calling the ARM API, but you gave permissions only on ASM API, you probably need to add your app's service principal to a role in your subscription. Find your subscription, then the Users blade (I think), and then add your app to a role there. You should be able to find it with its name.

Comment: You are correct! Many thanks, this has driven me crazy! It works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat in the comments the problem was found:

You are calling the Azure Resource Management API, but you gave permissions only on the Azure Service Management API. You need to add your app's service principal to a role in your subscription. Find your subscription, then the Access Control (IAM) blade, and then add your app to a role there. You should be able to find it with its name.

You can also add the service principal to a role on a resource group or even specific resources if you want to limit its capabilities.